# Chart.js doughnut chart isn't showing tooltip when you hover over the left/right of the doughnut

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have created a doughnut chart with an external legend and when you hover over the left or right of the doughnut no tooltip appears - whereas if you hover over the top/bottom of the doughnut a tooltip does appear.

The configuration I am using is as follows:

```
 const config = {
                type: 'doughnut',
                data: data,
                options: {
                    cutout: "85%",
                    plugins: {
                        htmlLegend: {
                            // ID of the container to put the legend in
                            containerID: 'legend-container',
                        },
                        legend: {
                            display: false,
                        }
                    }
                },
                plugins: [htmlLegendPlugin],
            };

            new Chart(
                document.getElementById('chartContainer'),
                config
            );
```

Does anyone know why the tooltip isn't appearing and how to resolve it? I am using chart.js 3.3.2.

Comment: It seems to be working fine, I can hover each part and it shows the tooltip normally, also if I set intersect to false I can also hover the cutout and it works fine

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/eptuys9q/6/

Comment: That seems to work fine for me even with only one data item which is what we have at the moment. I'll do some more digging as this is super strange.

Comment: If you can please share a reproducable link so people might be able to help you more

Comment: @LeeLenalee I have solved the problem - thanks for your assistance though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason this was happening was because I had used an absolutely positioned div to put a number into the middle of the chart.

This div had a width of 100% so was overlaying the middle parts of the chart meaning you couldn't hover over them. Reducing the width of the div to 60% and setting the 'left' value to 20% solved the problem.

Of note if this happens to you you might need to use different values depending on the size of the doughnut.